# Coversion of μmol/m2 to kg/ m2

Tags: carbon

I would like to convert `μmol C/m2` to `kg C/ ha`. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do it? Based on ChatGPT It can be converted as follows:

[image]

But I am not sure if this is correct. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's just unit conversion, so convert umol to mol ($10^{-6}$), multiply by the molar mass (~44 g/mol), and convert g to kg ($10^{-3}$) and $m^{-2}$ to $ha^{-1}$ ($10^4$).  The final conversion factor should be:

$$ 4.4\times10^1\times10^{-6}\times10^{-3}\times10^4 = 4.4\times10^{-4} \frac{kg/ha}{\mu mol/m^2} $$